# Bulk Insert Mismatch With Format File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I  am having an issue when trying to bulk insert I can't  get it to work with a format file with  the birthdate column all I get  is a mismatch error.
I get this error below
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 5 (BIRTHDATE). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4864). My format file is setup as datetime as well and the temp table is as well. Also the open_date column will throw the same error. Only way I have gotten it to work so far if I do a float.

```
(
    MEMBERNUMBER float
      ,[FIRSTNAME] varchar(255) null
      ,[MIDDLENAME] varchar(255) null
      ,[LASTNAME]varchar(255) null
      ,[BIRTHDATE] datetime null
      ,[GENDER] varchar(255) null
      ,[MARITALSTATUS] varchar(255) null
      ,[OCCUPATIONINDUSTRY] varchar(255) null
      ,[OCCUPATIONTITLE]varchar(255) null
      ,[ADDRESS1]varchar(255) null
      ,[ADDRESS2]varchar(255)null
      ,[CITY] varchar(255)null
      ,[STATE] varchar(255)null
      ,[POSTALCODE] float null
      ,[HOMEPHONE] varchar(255) null
      ,[CELLPHONE] varchar(255) null
      ,[WORKPHONE] varchar(255) null
      ,[EMAIL] varchar(255) null
      ,[ALTERNATEEMAIL] varchar(255) null
      ,[OPEN_DATE] datetime null
      ,[MARKETINGOPTION] varchar(255) null

)

BULK INSERT CSVTempData
FROM '\\eftroot\ftps\usr\EmailMarketing.csv'
WITH
(FormatFile = '\\EFTRoot\ftps\Usr\FormatFiles\Test.fmt')

-- format file here 
8.0
21

1   SQLFLT8   0   30  ","        1  MEMBERNUMBER        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2   SQLCHAR   0   255  ","       2  FIRSTNAME           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3   SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      3  MIDDLENAME          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4   SQLCHAR   0   255  ","       4  LASTNAME            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5   SQLDATETIME  0  9 ","     5 BIRTHDATE           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6   SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      6  GENDER              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7   SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      7  MARITALSTATUS       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8   SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      8  OCCUPATIONINDUSTRY  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9   SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      9  OCCUPATIONTITLE     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      10 ADDRESS1            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      11 ADDRESS2            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      12 CITY                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      13 STATE               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14  SQLFLT8   0   8   ","      14   POSTALCODE          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      15 HOMEPHONE           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16  SQLCHAR   0   255  ","       16 CELLPHONE           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      17 WORKPHONE           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      18 EMAIL               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19  SQLCHAR   0   255   ","      19 ALTERNATEEMAIL      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20  SQLDATETIME 0  9  ","      20   OPEN_DATE           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
21  SQLCHAR   0   255   "\r\n"   21 MARKETINGOPTION     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS




insert into ser.dbo.MembersNew

select *
from CSVTempData
```

Comment: Are you importing this directly from Excel data, by any chance? Excel stores dates as floating-point values, but SQL Server doesn't know how to handle that. Your CSV should be exported using `yyyy-MM-dd`, not merely as the way it's formatted in Excel but the actual value in the file. To do this in Excel you need (some variation of) `TEXT(A1, "yyyy-MM-dd")` (but both the `,` and the characters used in the format string are subject to localization, which is how that goes in Excel). Alternatively, import the float and then convert to a date with `DATEADD(DAY, [value] - 2, '1900-01-01')`.

Comment: Not sure if I will be able to convert it because the csv has 40k of records is there a way to convert it with column itself?

Comment: A `BULK INSERT` cannot convert on its own. If you have the data as-is in a table with a `FLOAT` column, you can use `SELECT .. INTO CsvDataFinal` to transform the data after importing it. Alternatively, you can use `SELECT .. FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ..)` to transform the data on the fly. (40K rows isn't much, by the way, neither for SQL Server nor for Excel.)